# How to scroll to a part of the page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code scrolls the user to the bottom of the page:

```
var $elem = $('body');
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.height()}, 800);
```

How can it be modified to take the user to the part of the page where there is a h3 tag with the id "myTitle":

```
<h3 id="myTitle">Hello</h3>
```

Comment: I suggest using http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ plugin, it is very nice and lightweight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
var $elem = $("#myTitle");
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $elem.offset().top}, 800);
```

using [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset).

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/naTjL/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the offset of the element from the top:

`var position = $("#myTitle").offset().top;`

You can then use that as the value to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a brilliant example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

That even works with JS turned off. Additionally this adds the `#myTitle` to the URL allowing bookmarking.

Comment: @Mrchief: I can imagine he refers to the default behaviour when clicking on an anchor that refers to another element (which does not scroll of course).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html, body').scrollTop($("#myTitle").offset().top)
```